# How to dynamically generate Validations for the Front end depending upon the Logic

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, drools

Consider the page below. As in the image I have attached.
[image]

Now my problem is that I have multiple clients accessing the same page as given below. Now consider that each client has their own requirement such as:-

1. Name is mandatory for some clients not for others.
2. Age is mandatory for some clients but not for others along with some specific validations like age<20 or age>30 etc.
3. Search is also optional depending upon the clients.

Now I am searching for any such tools or technologies or methods that could help me to sort out the issue of dynamically validating the fields as well as hiding and showing the fields depending upon my clients. Please let me know any tools or technologies that can help in order to solve the above problem. I also heard about rule engine and templating .... Is it possible to work together with it to achieve the same. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why hibernate-validator would not work here. You implement the validation as you want, by implementing an interface and creating your own validation annotations if needed. This is a server-side validation btw.

Showing or not some content in case of JSP is done with conditional :

```
c:when/c:choose
```

for example, assuming it's JSP you are using.

Comment: What if I have multiple input boxes and some clients want it and others dont? Then what is the scope of dealing with it? In case of JSP page. I understand the JSP conditional tags that you mentioned but still consider it for a set of 100 separate clients. What can be the scenario? Would appreciate your help.

Comment: @ShivKumarGanesh I would try to group stuff as much a possible, for example 10 text boxes inside a div and output or not the div itself. I do not really know a better way to do it.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I am still venturing out to find out solutions that can help me to generalize this in a much better way. Lets see if I am able to find out anything better :). Thanks anyways.

Comment: @ShivKumarGanesh I am interested too btw. :) Thank You==upvote on SO btw

Comment: Done!! ;) Hope to solve it soon. Using something called Drools.